# Raphael opacity not displaying on IE

Tags: javascript, raphael, opacity

I'm having a problem with the opacity of a div when my site is viewed on Internet Explorer. Using `Raphael 2.0` (un-minified) I create a rectangle using the following code:

```
var rIn = Raphael("myDiv", "100%", "100%");
rIn.rect(0, 0, "100%", "100%").attr({fill:"black", stroke:"none", opacity:0.6});
```

In my `CSS` files if I have transparent divs using the `opacity` tag, I also write it include `filter` which seems to work fine for IE.

```
opacity:0.6; filter: alpha(opacity = 60);
```

However, Raphael does not appear to allow `filter` as a property, so this rectangle does not show up at all. This is only a problem on IE - it works on FF/Chrome/Safarai on Win/Mac without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

`filter` only works for IE5-7. To support IE8, you need this property as well **before** your `filter` property:

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
```

This [QuirksMode article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html) should help you as well.

---

Actually, try a class:

```
.opacity60 {
  opacity: 0.6;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}
```

And set your rectangle's class to `opacity60` via a `setAttribute('class', 'opacity60')` call.

Comment: Thanks @Blender. Can I also use a similar property for the Raphael attribute?

Comment: Add a class to the Raphael object.

Comment: I declared a class in my `.css` and tried setting the attributes using the following `rIn.rect.setAttribute('class', 'opacity60')` but I got the following error message in IE: `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'setAttribute'`

Comment: refer to the `rect`'s underlying element, like so: `rIn.rect.node.setAttribute('class', 'opacity60')`.

Comment: I tried that suggestion @EliranMalka but I got the following error message `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'setAttribute': object is null or undefined`. I did declare a class in my CSS.

Comment: well that seems like a logical problem, which narrows down the problem scope. now you can use defensive coding by `undefined` / `null` checks, and that should do it.

Comment: ok it seems like a known issue that [someone had already addressed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031354/raphael-div-opacity-not-working-on-ie).