# Raphael div opacity not working on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, raphael, opacity

I'm trying to figure out how to make rectangles with opacities that work on IE (FF/Chrome/Safari are all fine). I've tried creating a class in my CSS file

```
.opacity60 {
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}
```

and then tried to create a rectangle using the following code:

```
       var rIn = Raphael("sideIn", "100%", "100%");
       rIn.rect(0, 0, "100%", "100%").attr({fill:"black", stroke:"none",
opacity:0.6 });
       rIn.rect.node.setAttribute('class', 'opacity60')
```

However, I get the following error in the IE console (it does not work on FF either):

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'setAttribute': object
is null or undefined
```

I am basing this code from the question that I asked on this [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959427/raphael-opacity-not-displaying-on-ie), but as I can't get the suggested approach to work I'm wondering if there is something else that I am doing wrong. I've also asked on the Raphael list but there have been no suggested solutions there either.

Comment: What happens if you just set the node's .className property instead?

Comment: @Mitya How do I do that? Would it just be `rIn.rect.node.className('opacity60')` ?

Comment: `rIn.rect.node.className('opacity60')`does not work either....

Comment: className is a property, not a method, so it would be .className = 'opacity60'

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you simply can't set opacity for VML elements via CSS classes.  See for example, [this question where this gap is discussed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661154/is-it-possible-to-set-fill-and-stroke-colors-and-opacity-on-vml-paths-using-css)

You'll need to use Raphael's native `.attr({opacity: .5})` or set the VML element's *opacity* attribute directly.  In general, the Raphael API is there to shield you from these kind of inconsistencies, though it is frustrating that you can't separate your style rules out to a stylesheet.

One thing you can do to keep some separation between visual encodings is to write all your style information as objects in a designated area in your code:

```
var RECT_STYLE = {
    opacity: .5, 
    fill: "#ff0000", 
    stroke: "#333333",
    stroke-width: 1
}

var OVAL_STYLE = {
    opacity: .9, 
    fill: "#ffFF00", 
    stroke: "#000000",
    stroke-width: 5
}
//etc...
```

Then set them like:

```
rect.attr(RECT_STYLE);
oval.attr(OVAL_STYLE);
```